# Phonegap display waiting message until device location is received

Tags: javascript, cordova

Hi all I am trying to display waiting message until device location is not received.My code is:

```
function getLocation()
{
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);
}
```

I tried  navigator.notification.activityStart() and loadingStart() but they are not working.I am trying window. nothing is happening, should i import any plugins for that?

```
window.plugins.waitingDialog.show("Your dialog text");
```

Can someone help pls...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this ?

```
function getLocation()
{
    //display your waiting message
    document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = "waiting message";

    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);
}

function onSuccess()
{
    document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = "success";
}

function onSuccess()
{
    document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = "error";
}
```

Comment: It is working but i want a dialogue box that can block screen. And in onSuccess i have an ajax call with alert boxes.

Comment: Thanks gaepi, I got it working with you help.I added a gif image in div. code: document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = "<img src='ajax_loader.gif'>"; and later in onSuccess   document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = "";                                     Its working fine now... :-) thanks again